# Make one of my many JS scripts load in the footer (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

From my previous problem I have discovered I have to move one single plugins script to be loaded in the footer rather then the header (o other items can load first)

Is there a way (either in wordpress, or the actually plugin) to tell it to send one plugin to load in the footer somewhere? Maybe the location where ever it gives instructions to load in the header can be changed?

Comment: Which plugin are we talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last argument for `wp_enqueue_script` is a Boolean whether to load the script in the footer:

> Normally scripts are placed in the `<head>` section. If this parameter is true the script is placed at the bottom of the `<body>`. This requires the theme to have the `wp_footer()` hook in the appropriate place. Note that you have to enqueue your script before wp_head is run, even if it will be placed in the footer.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

---

So, use this before the head is outputted:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'handle_name',
    'source/file/path',
    array('some_dependency'),
    '1.0'
    true // <-- this is what sends it down to the footer
);
```

Then add `wp_footer()` before closing off the body:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> <--- was allready there
<?php wp_enqueue_script('share-this', plugins_url('share-this/wp-st-opt.js.php'), array('jquery'), '1', true); ?> <--- not sure if this is correct, not sure what to fill the array with, or the numeric value. Also in the plugin there is a php file aswell as a js file, does that change anything?
<?php wp_head(); ?><--- was allready there

Comment: If the boolean is definitely set to true, then you need to look at where wp_footer is being called in your theme, as @Joseph Silber suggests. Also, what are you using to confirm where the script is in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) with $in_footer

[Example usage](http://lesterchan.net/wordpress/2009/01/26/loading-javascript-in-footer-in-wordpress-28/)

```
wp_enqueue_script('wp-polls', plugins_url('wp-polls/polls-js.js'), array('jquery'), '2.50', true);
```

Comment: <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> <-- allready there
<?php wp_enqueue_script('share-this', plugins_url('share-this/wp-st-opt.js.php'), array('jquery'), '1', true); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>  <-- allready there

Does not work, wonder what I am doing wrong :(